# Plausible? Mechanics of Floating Continents/Islands on Gas Giant (with sea)

Tags: magic, planets, physics

Just thought of how a gas giant would have the physics to entertain floating islands/gigantic landmasses + a floating sea of water. Pretty much just wrote down whatever i could think of.

Basically, a huge gas giant that is probably the size of the solar system --> endless skiesssss

Physics is handwaved by the presence of a gas called Aether and microorganisms that feed on this gas create exotic phenomena that allow life to flourish on the landmasses. Is it possible/ do my wandering thoughts make sense? XD

Sea of Clouds

Floating Continents --> primary landmasses of life, forms from asteroids crashing into atmosphere, aether slows entry enough that it doesnt burn up, aether ore condenses when not free floating (ie. hitting + landing on the asteroid) and acts as glue, multiple collisions with other asteroids forms landmass.

Smaller continents get turned into Colony ships that wander the sky expanse to find new continents, sentient species create Huge Colony Landmasses wandering the endless skies. Aether ores embedded in continents as landmasses collide and build up upon each other. Renewables resources but takes up to 100 years to regenerate a mine. like fossil fuel but way faster. Therefore sustainable harvesting --> policy adopted by most species.

Exotic Gas called aether lighter/heaver than air depending on concentration and matter state. Light aether content floats. Higher aether content sinks.

Aether also insulate + Ozone layer --> therefore no ice age due to no molten core.

Water forms the calm belt - a floating ocean, "deepest" in the middle of the belt , but not deep enough, as light can still go through, water is not "deep" but the belt is endless, presumably surrounds the whole planet.

The Calm Belt is linked to Aether in a liquid state. Strangely, liquid aether's density is constantly changing but extremely hydrophilic attracting water, thus the Calm Belt is never the depth anywhere. Furthermore, some islands may have liquid Aether, causing water vapour to go there instead, before falling off the island as they condense and flow off the island thanks to gravity.

Aether Microorgansims also weirdly attracted to lightrays, under the calm belt Aether Microorgansims will group up so that it is hit by light rays, then microorganisms reflects the light, lighting up thus lighting up islands under the topmost islands, or under the calm belt.

As many floating continents, we get separate biomes. If sink down, crushed by water pressure only ever goes deeper. Humans actually have a organ that produce Aether in the lungs, prevents them from sinking too fast, develop slight floating/ gliding capabilities.

Aether also source of energy manipulation (magic) and is used as fuel source.

High aether content humans can actually fly around as if in Zero G, as Aether can create zero g fields under conscious mental control.

Many creatures that evolved to adapt to Aether, such as Skywhales. Many creatures that evolved in specific landmass biome.

```
**Space**
**Stratosphere**
**Islands** (Small Aether Ore Content, Lvl 1)
**Continents** (Some Aether Ore Content, Lvl 2) (Water Flows Down) (Aether ore forms in continents, floats them, density lower than liquid form)
**Islands** (Large Aether Ore Content, Lvl 3)
**Surface Calm Belt**
**Deep Calm Belt** (liquid Aether --> ranging density point, floats, microorgism that feed on liquid aether are extremely hydrophilic)
**Surface Calm Belt**
**Islands** (Very Large Aether Ore Content, Lvl 4) (Aether Ore density now higher than liquid, sinks)
**Continents** (Super Large Aether Ore Content, Lvl 5) (Water Flows Up) -(Handwave molecule that attaches to H20 that causes vapour to sink instead of float? microorganism that survives on specific lightwave filtered by Calm Belt?) -(same molecules attach to aether ore causing density to be lower than aether liquid)
**Islands** (Ginormous Aether Ore Content, Lvl 6)
**Clouds** (Below sea of clouds is nothing) (atmospheric pressure similar to deepsea, will crush anything, including the microogranisms, releasing H20 molecule that floats back up as water vapour rejoing the calm belt)
```

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I have some problem understanding what you are asking, please chop off the non necessary parts and explain the problem you ask us to solve. You can take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand our standards.

Comment: If you’re handwaving a solar system sized gas giant then frankly whatever you want is plausible.

Comment: You would need to have another large mass near enough that its gravity would prevent these floating landmasses from being  pulled into the center of the gas giant. Something of similar mass that was relatively close.

Comment: Is there something that either keeps the islands from being pulled towards the center due to gravity, or lets them ignore air resistance to stay at orbital velocity? (and if the answer to either of those is 'magic', then no, it's not plausible according to normal physics)

Comment: Hi Lyssia! Welcome to Worldbuilding! Please take a moment to explore the [help] and [tour]. They will help you learn about what kinds of questions are allowable here and how to write good questions.  So, there are some flagged issues with your question: it seems unclear and cluttered with unnecessary stuff. I'm going to vote to close your question. Not because it's bad (it is actually good and on topic!) but simply because of basic issues. Take this as an opportunity to edit and focus on one single issue by asking one single question without a lot of background.

Comment: A gas giant the size of the solar system would pretty much be impossible as the mass of it all would exert so much gravity that it will probably fuse elements together and form a star. But seeing you already have the details of the world in place, there's not really much to say, you can make it exist as you will.